# RelativeLayout doesn't fit in all screen sizes android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am developing my first application in android and i am stuck with my xml layout. I have 5 buttons placed vertically in my layout under relativelayout. I am using sony xperia M and according to my screen size the layout looks perfectly fine but for big screens the layout is messed up. When i run my app in a device which has a big screen size the buttons don't have proper gap in between. How can i make my layout to fit all screen sizes ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/blue3"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Tasks"
    android:id="@+id/mytasks_btn"
    android:onClick="mytask"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Task"
    android:id="@+id/addtask_btn"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:onClick="addtask"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mytasks_btn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Current Location"
    android:id="@+id/shw_loc_btn"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:onClick="shwlocn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Nearby"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="searchnear"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shw_loc_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:text="Location Distance"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:onClick="locdis"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider wrapping your buttons inside another layout, for example LinearLayout. If you want your buttons to be evenly distributed on the screen you should use code like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Very important is to set children's heights to match_parent and set proper layout_weight values.